# Is it posible to send multiple message to Google Home through DialogFlow?

Tags: google-home, dialogflow-es

On facebook Chatbot or others platform we can send message directly to the user.
So for one question we can send multiple answer.

Now, that i'm developing for Google Home, I need to do the same.
I didn't find this opttion.
Dialogflow HTTP call to my server is the only output available.

So is there anything i missed to send message back to user in case I have a multiple messages answer?
(Or do I have to bufferise very message my hook creates before sending it back?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The conversation model for the Google Assistant is different - you can only send a message to the user in response to the user sending you a message. You can only send a single response, but it may have multiple parts (up to two Simple responses, containing messages, plus other features such as cards and carousels).

If you need to send multiple things back - you may need to rethink how you're doing it or how much you're sending back at a time. The Assistant is primarily for audible responses, and a long audible response is generally not a good UX.